# WeakReferenced object is not garbage collected after calling System.gc()

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, weak-references

I am a fresh new learner of Java. I'm now learning the concept of WeakReference. I came across a problem which probably looks stupid but I just wanna figure out the reason. The problem is: according to Java doc,  "Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed."

So I did this small test:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference; 

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        WeakReference<A> wr = new WeakReference<>(a);
        a = null;

        A a1 = wr.get();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(a1);

        try {
            System.gc();

            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(a1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize( ) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": See ya, nerds!");
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that after GC running, `wr.get()` could still return object which I expected null, and the method `finalize()` was not invoked. So what went wrong? Thanks for your kind help in advance! :)

Comment: Great first question, by the way. It's not always easy for a newcomer to write a question which fulfills all the criteria that we try to encourage but you've pretty much nailed it. The best I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The premise of your test is flawed. `System.gc()` is only a *hint* to run the garbage collector. It is frequently ignored.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--):

> Calling the gc method **suggests** that the Java Virtual Machine
>   expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the
>   memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control
>   returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best
>   effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

(Emphasis mine)

In future, you may use the VM options `-verbose:gc` and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to see what the garbage collector is doing.

---

More importantly, you are also *very quickly* taking the reference out of the weak reference and putting it back into a strong reference:

```
A a = new A();
WeakReference<A> wr = new WeakReference<>(a);
a = null; // no strong references remain
A a1 = wr.get(); // the instance now has a strong reference again
```

Unless garbage collection occurs between these exact two instructions, the object will not be garbage collected.

If you remove `a1`, your code behaved as you would expect when I ran it (though, because of the first part of my answer, your mileage may vary):

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        WeakReference<A> wr = new WeakReference<>(a);
        a = null;

        System.out.println(a);

        try {
            System.gc(); // instance of A is garbage collected
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(wr.get());
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize( )
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": See ya, nerds!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Michael! So, theoretically speaking, if the System.gc() is commited by JVM, the second time the result that wr.get() returns would surely be null, right? If only I could see it in person lol

Comment: @Kyleeeeeeeeee I conducted a test with some additional VM options (see my updated answer) and in fact my VM was indeed honouring the hint, though it's not guaranteed. The much more likely problem is that you're giving the object a strong reference very quickly after removing the previous strong reference.

Comment: Now I got the result I expected, and understand the reason why the former codes went wrong. Many thanks Michael! :D

Comment: @Kyleeeeeeeeee No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: @Michael AFAIK every VM honors `System.gc()`, it's just that there's the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` flag, which is a first aid against misbehaving libraries. When you yourself start the JVM, you can (but shouldn't) rely on `System.gc()` working.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `System.gc()` does not ensure a garbage collection. Instead, it's just a hint that "It's a good time to run garbage collection".

Secondly, in your code when you put `A a1 = wr.get();` before calling `System.gc()`, it creates a new strong reference to the same object referenced by `a`, thus even if garbage collection runs, your object will not be garbage collected.

As we have two tasks in hand

1. Ensure garbage collection
2. Don't keep any strong reference to the object you want to be garbage collected

Let's do little modification to your code

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        WeakReference<A> wr = new WeakReference<>(a);
        a = null;
        // A a1 = wr.get(); Removing this, this does our 2nd task
        System.out.println(a);
        // System.out.println(a1); Removing this as a1 does not exists anymore
        try {
            while (null != wr.get()) { // 1st task done, the loop ensures sending the hint until your object collected
                System.gc();
                // Thread.sleep(10000); it does not have impact
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(wr.get()); // Obviously prints null
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": See ya, nerds!");
    }
}
```